# How to use data from a gs bucket as a keras dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have the following code, in which I want to load data from a bucket to keras, code that I'm running using the tensorflow cloud:

```
ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(kitti_train, image_size=(375,1242),\
                                                         batch_size=6, shuffle=False, label_mode=None)
```

where I've tried both the full url of the bucket for kitti_train and also the gs://bucket-name url for kitti_train. But none seem to work. How to fix this?

I get: No such file or directory.

Comment: did you solve your question?